# Unable to hide Action Bar before starting another activity

Tags: android-layout, android-activity

I'm trying to first create an activity, then after 2 seconds, I want to hide the action bar and then after another 2 secs, I want to start another activity but this code - `getActionBar().hide()` isn't working. Here is my code -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    //final ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();

    Thread timer1 = new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                getActionBar().hide();
            }
        }
    };
    timer1.start();

    Thread timer2 = new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                Intent intent = new Intent("app.lost_and_found_0.STARTINGPOINT");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    timer2.start();
}
```

Is there something wrong I'm doing wrong?
My application theme is set to `Theme.Holo.Light` in manifest file.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but maybe just setting it to a blank action bar would help you

Answer (score 0):

Use getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar(). As on the class, you need to extend ActionBarActivity.

Comment: I'm using API 15 as the minimum.